# Mercurial says that I'm on a feature branch even after I tell him 'hg update default'

Tags: version-control, mercurial, branch, dvcs, branching-and-merging

I have created a feature branch in the next fashion:
`hg branch feature/issue-number`.

I made a commit with my changes, and wanted to push this branch.
I typed `hg push --new-branch -b feature/issue-number`, and mercurial said: `abort: unknown branch 'feature/issue-number'`.

I typed `hg branch` and it printed `feature/issue-number`.

I typed `hg update default` and it printed `0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved`.

Then I typed `hg branch` again. I expected to see `default` in output, but there was still `feature/issue-number`.

Can anyone explain me what's going on?

Comment: if you do `hg log -b feature/issue` does it report the changesets you expect on that branch? hg is behaving as if the new branch was created after the commit in question.

Comment: @Edward: it tells: abort, unknown revision

Comment: Are you sure that you created the commit *after* you created the branch? It seems you did it the other way round.

Comment: @Rudi: I'm not really sure in it. Maybe, I did the commit first.

Comment: What does `hg branches` say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit. In Mercurial, branch are  permanent information recorded in the commit itself. After you typed `hg branch babar` your "working copy" got changed to branch `babar` but there won't be any commit on this branch until you create an actual commit from your working copy with `hg commit`. You can use `hg summary` at any time to undersrand the state of your repository.

Mercurial has a lighter concept called "bookmark" that allows to reference changesets without permanente records in the commit itself. You should check it out before going commiting yourself into using named branch.